# An error occurred on the server This event has been recorded

Tags: bug, login, openid, stack-exchange-openid

Can't login to external website by openid.stackexchange.com

https://openid.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/openid/provider

shows error:

```
   An error occurred on the server This event has been recorded.
```

Problem started today, before was ok.

I succesfully loged in openid.stackexchange.com, but openid don't transfer authentication to external website.

Comment: What is your target site? are you trying to login in meta.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Please provide the exact openID url you're entering, and also the name of the external site (if possible). I can't reproduce this.

Comment: Target site: http://sqlanywhere-forum.sybase.com/ , I am using Google Chrome

Comment: Firefox the same error effect

Comment: The same error appears since January on http://ask.fedoraproject.org

Comment: Looks like a common issue on askbot and some OSQA sites.

Comment: So what's the reason? If "This event has been recorded" then someone on stackexchange staff should know the answer and provide more detailed data for us?