# Logging into Ask LibreOffice with my Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: bug, status-declined, login, stack-exchange-openid

If I'm on http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/account/signin/?next=/en/, I click on OpenID and then enter https://openid.stackexchange.com and click Log In, I get a page that says:

```
An error occurred on the server

This event has been recorded.

If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.
```

I clicked report it and here I am reporting it! Using Firefox 26

Comment: This may be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216291/249247

Comment: This happens also with IE11. Other sites using stackexchange openid seem to work fine.

Comment: This also happens with http://ask.fedoraproject.org It started in January.

Comment: I wonder who can be contacted on this. I've tried placing a bounty on this question as well, but there seems to be no response whatsoever.

Comment: Same problem here but no solution at sight.. I tried it without https and also with the https everyvery addon for Firefox diabled, because I read that might cause the problem. No change though.

Comment: Looks like a common issue on askbot and some OSQA sites.

Comment: me three.  Duplicate questions identified but incorrectly marked as "already answered".

Comment: @Oded more and more people are reporting this, nothing you can do on SE's side?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - not really, something broken on the OSQA side of things :(

Comment: @Oded so maybe post some official answer like "Not on our side" so we can have a reference to close all others too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked !

I did not use the default `https://openid.stackexchange.com/` but the url pointing to your specific id.
In your SE openid profile, click on `Use your own URL to log in` and copy the url matching `openid2.local_id` (Something like https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/UUID).

You may have to login to SE if not already, but eventually, you will be connected to AskLO through openid.SE

Answer (score 1):

There is something broken on the OSQA/askBot side of this - nothing we can do about it.

Possibly the OpenId library version - some versions of OSQA work absolutely fine with the Stack Exchange OpenId provider.

Comment: Any chance of filing a bug report on the OSQA site or if there already is one, perhaps posting a link to it?

Comment: There's this  http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/11140/how-can-we-encourage-more-people-to-sign-in-to-the-ask-site/

Comment: Bug filed in LibreOffice infra bugtracker: [Users can't log in to Ask LibreOffice site with StackExchange / StackOverflow OpenID](https://redmine.documentfoundation.org/issues/627)