# Getting "An error occurred on the server" when trying to login to ask.libreoffice.org

Tags: support, stack-exchange-openid

Trying to login to ask.libreoffice.org. Their login page is at

http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/account/signin/

Where I click openID button and key in url `https://openid.stackexchange.com/`. Then I click "Sign In", and I get:

> ### An error occurred on the server
>
> **This event has been recorded.**
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

[image: openid error on the server]

Am I doing something wrong, or is it broken?

Using Firefox 27.0.1, Windows 7. The red plugin shown in the screenshot is lastpass, which should not have an impact here. I'm using the same login for stackexchange sites, where the login works fine. Tested also on IE 11 without any plugins, and seeing the same behaviour.

Test from another site, [livejournal.com](http://www.livejournal.com/identity/login.bml?type=openid), worked without issues.

Comment: Well, it does say "An error occurred on the server", So I guess it's safe to say the server is broken.

Comment: @Arjan the red icon with the white star is a plugin to save user accounts & passwords. I'm quite sure it has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: @Arjan it links to here, which is why I created this message

Comment: @Arjan and yes, I am using the same id to login to stack exchange sites, although the session is usually remembered so I don't go through the login page very often

Comment: Just retested and loggin in to stack exchange sites using the openid way works fine, but from ask.libreoffice.org there's still a server error.

Comment: The plugin is lastpass. It shouldn't have impact.

Comment: Somebody else [seems to have reported this as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217742/logging-into-ask-libreoffice-with-my-stack-exchange-openid?rq=1), with no feedback.

Comment: @eis can you log in to other non-SE sites with your Stack Exchange OpenID? Important to know if it's only specific to that site, or global problem with the OpenID.

Comment: @ShadowWizard can you give an example site to test on?

Comment: Well, any site using OpenID... not near a computer right now but simple Google should find such site quickly

Comment: Tested with http://www.livejournal.com/identity/login.bml?type=openid, works without issues.