# Cannot sign in to third party website with stackexchange openid

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-openid

I tried providing StackExchange's openid url (https://openid.stackexchange.com) as a login method over at ask.libreoffice.org and got an SE server error:

> An error occurred on the server
>
> This event has been recorded.
>
> If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it.

Well I believe I did encounger this error in error, so am reporting it.

Comment: What browser? What site? Were you logged in to the OpenId provider at the time?

Comment: This is an ongoing issue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217742/logging-into-ask-libreoffice-with-my-stack-exchange-openid) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216291/an-error-occurred-on-the-server-this-event-has-been-recorded). You may wish to chime in there, but no use in splitting up the conversation further.